# spring integration distributed parallel Scatter Gather pattern

Tags: spring-integration, distributed

I need to implement the following architecture:

I have large Order that must be split into smaller order( parallel) and  send to Downstream async rest end point .

Down stream ordering API publish message to a reply queue ( kafka/rabbitmq) after completing order ( failed or success)
with correlation ids .

Need to have aggregate listener to collect all the responses and send the final out put to caller.

I am thinking of using spring integration Scatter gather pattern  and other useful Spring features.

Can you help me show an example of how such an architecture can be implemented with the help of Spring-integration

Answer (score 0):

> large Order that must be split into smaller order( parallel)

This is not what scatter-gather is designed for. Its purpose to do many requests for the same input, e.g. ask dealerships for car quote and then choose the best one for you.

What you are asking is more like a splitter-aggregator.

So, you just perform a split function on your order object and produce as many items as you need into its output channel. And this one has to be an `ExecutorChannel` to be able to process those splitted items in parallel.

Since you talk about a reply to the original client, you cannot make your aggregator distributed (several instances of the same application), but you will still a gain an async, parallel processing benefit just with that `ExecutorChannel`. don't forget to carry on a `replyChannel` header throughout your flow, so an aggregator in the end would know where to produce a reply.